# How to show that this stat statement is true

Tags: r, statistical-significance

Someone made this statement:

```
1 out of 1000 corresponds to a proportion of 0,1%. In this case you 
have a chance of 37% of having 0 outcome, significance level 63%. 
3 out of 1000 translating to a proportion of 0,3% has a 5% chance to hit 0.
```

Are the above statement correct and how one arrives on proving this is indeed correct.

The above statement goes something like this:

So lets assume that I observe 0 cases out of 1000. Can I say that assuming hypothetically 1 dead out of 1000 would give me a 37% chance of observing 0?
Or otherwise what is the probability of observing 0 cases if one assumes (historically) 1/1000, under 63% confidence and 95% confidence level.

Solution, is this correct?

```
dbinom(0, 1000, prob = 1/1000) # gives ~36%
```

and

```
dbinom(0, 1000, prob = 3/1000) # gives ~5%
```

Comment: Uh, what? Sorry, I don't understand the statement. The first sentence is correct. The second sentence seems to misunderstand what statistical significance is. The third sentence is completely unclear to me. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Well this is the statement towards probability of observing 0 cases (survival out of n cases). So lets assume that I observe 0 cases out of 1000. Can I say that assuming hypothetically 1 dead out of 1000 would give me a 37% chance of observing 0 instead of >=1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah. Well, this seems to be a *very* badly formulated way of saying:

> We perform 1000 independent trials, each with a success probability of 0.001. Then we have a chance of 37% to observe no successes at all.

This is a true statement, `pbinom(0,1000,1/1000)`. Note how the statement in the question does not mention the number of trials, only the proportion of successes - but without the number of trials, we can't say anything about the probability of observing $k$ successes.

If we increase the success probability to 0.003, then yes, we only have a chance of about 5% to observe no success at all, `pbinom(0,1000,3/1000)`.

"significance level 63%" - our situation has nothing to do with statistical significance.

Comment: perhaps additional question. Can we make this inference also without distributional assumptions? Or how large assumptions are we making here? I know that both with normal and Poisson binomial approx. distr. can be made.

Comment: Well, you can work with a Poisson distribution with a *mean* of $\lambda=\frac{1}{1000}$ etc., as per [Dave2e's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/468861/1352). But then talking about "1 out of 1000" is even more misleading. Better to talk explicitly about what the parameter is: a "success probability" for the binomial case, or a "mean" for the Poisson, and add the specific distributional assumption you make.

Comment: And no, you can't do anything without *some* assumptions. You could also have a very strange distribution with just two possible outcomes, $P(0)=p$ and $P(n)=1-p$ for some $n\neq 0$. If, e.g., $n=10$ and $p=0.9999$, you again have an expectation of $\frac{1}{1000}$, but your probability of observing only zeros will be different. All in all, sorry to say, but your question is very unclear.

Comment: Many thanks Stephan. I have given all information I have had. Anyway all clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential way of solving this problem is with a Poisson Distribution.

In this case $\lambda$ is 1/1000.  So the probability of of observing 0 events with a single trial is:

```
ppois(0, 1/1000)
#[1] 0.9990005
```

Thus it is 99.9% chance that no events will occur.  Now if we are interested in testing a 1000 independent trials then the overall probability is:

```
ppois(0, 1/1000)^1000
#[1] 0.3678794
```

So a 36.7% chance that there will be no events in 1000 random, independent trials.

Now repeating for the $\lambda=$ 3/1000 probability case:

```
ppois(0, 3/1000)
#[1] 0.9970045

#drawing 1000 possible options
ppois(0, 3/1000)^1000
#[1] 0.04978707
```

Now the chance of having 0 events per 1000 trials fall to ~5%.

Comment: Many thanks, actually I was keen on using more Poisson distribution in particularly for smaller size samples.